# How can I access value of ID to find the average?

Tags: java, static-methods

I have static method Das which will take 2 objects of type Car and return average value of id. I have difficulty accessing id to find the average. Any help will be appreciated

Here is my code

```
public class Car {

private int id;
private String name;

public Car(int id, String name)
{
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
}

public static int Das( Car C1 , Car C2) {
{
return (C1.id + C2.id)/2 ;
}

// getter and setter
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Car car1 = new Car(1,"A");
Car car2 = new Car(2,"V");
double A= Das(car1,car2);
System.out.println(A);
}}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I am unable to access id in the method

Comment: I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out what the average of two id's would be. To me, an id is a specific identifier that separates objects from one another. The id has no other value.

Comment: That is because they are private

Comment: Isn't "average" of two values is simply their sum divided by two?

Comment: So is there any way I can access them, id =50 and id=60 that are being passed from main method

Comment: Make them public

Comment: They have to be `private`

Comment: What does "unable to access them" mean exactly?  What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Create a property to access them?

Comment: Karan rather than voting to close your question, you could simply delete it.

Comment: The private access of the id has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `int` return where you will lose fractions, do it as follows.

```
public static int findAveCustomerId(Customer C1 , Customer C2) {
   return (C1.id + C2.id)/2;
}
```

For a `double` return where you won't lose fractions

```
public static double findAveCustomerId(Customer C1 , Customer C2) {
   return (C1.id + C2.id)/2.; // notice the decimal point.
}
```

Comment: Not certain what mean.  The static method has access to the private values because they are referenced within the class that declared them.

Comment: The OP declared the method static.  I did not explain or demonstrate how to call it.  Nor was that the question.

Comment: The OP wanted to who how to calculate the average.  Note  the NEED HELP HERE comment.  That is what I focused on.  And no offense taken whatsover.